# Efficient reasoning in modular arithmetic

Tags: isabelle, modular-arithmetic

I decided to prove the following theorem:

```
theory Scratch
  imports Main
begin

lemma "(3::int)^k mod 4 = 1 ⟷ even k"
proof (cases "even k")
  case True
    then obtain l where "2*l = k" by auto
    then show ?thesis
      using power_mult [of "(3::int)" 2 l]
      and power_mod [of "(9::int)" 4 l] by auto
next
  case False
    then obtain l where "2*l + 1 = k" using odd_two_times_div_two_succ by blast
    then have "(3::int)^k mod 4 = 3"
      using power_mult [of "(3::int)" 2 l ]
      and mod_mult_right_eq [of "(3::int)" "9^l" 4]
      and power_mod [of "(9::int)" 4 l]
      by auto
    then show ?thesis using `odd k` by auto
qed

end
```

The proof is accepted by Isabelle, but to my taste, there is way too much trivial detail as to how calculations `mod 4` are performed:

```
    then have "(3::int)^k mod 4 = 3"
      using power_mult [of "(3::int)" 2 l ]
      and mod_mult_right_eq [of "(3::int)" "9^l" 4]
      and power_mod [of "(9::int)" 4 l]
      by auto
```

Apart from the application of `power_mult`, this is only application of various rules on what
parts of expressions may be safely reduced. Is there a proof method that can infer detail like this automatically?

(I'm also open to any other comments about my proof style - one thing that bothers me is the repetitive `::int`)

Comment: For that precise proof, `lemma "(3::int)^k mod 4 = 1 ⟷ even k"
  apply (cases ‹even k›)
   apply (auto elim!: oddE simp: power_mult
      simp flip: mod_mult_right_eq[of 3 ‹9^_›] power_mod[of 9])
  done` actually works. But you don't want to compress your proofs like that in general. And I did not find a way to torture simp into doing the simplification without instantiation. Simprocs would be useful…

Answer (score 0):

Following some discussion on IRC and subsequent experimentation, I have learned the following:

Firstly, the `a mod c = b mod c` is somewhat verbose. `HOL-Number_Theory.Cong` defines the notation `[a = b] (mod c)`, which is much more pleasant to use.

```
theory Scratch
  imports
    Main
    "HOL-Number_Theory.Cong" (* or "HOL-Number_Theory.Number_Theory",
                                but that requires some more computation *)
begin
```

(note that this will make Isabelle compile the theory, which can take some time. You might want to run `isabelle jedit -l HOL-Number_Theory`, so that this happens only once.)

A one-line proof of the theorem will still require manually instantiating the relevant lemmas. However, it is usually a better idea to spell out the steps some more. This will allow the tactics to infer how the theorems should be instantiated, while leaving more useful detail for the *human*.

```
proof (cases "even k")
  case True
  then obtain l where "2*l = k" by auto
  then have "[3^k = (3^2)^l] (mod 4)" (is "cong _ ... _")
    by (auto simp add: power_mult)
  also have "[... = (1::int)^l] (mod 4)" (is "cong _ ... _")
    by (intro cong_pow) (simp add: cong_def)
  also have "[... = 1] (mod 4)" by auto
  finally have "[3^k = 1::int] (mod 4)".
  thus ?thesis using `even k` by blast
next
  case False
  then obtain l where "2*l + 1 = k"
    using oddE by blast
  then have "[3^k = 3^(2*l+1)] (mod 4)" (is "cong _ ... _") by auto
  also have "[... = (3^2)^l * 3] (mod 4)" (is "cong _ ... _")
    by (metis power_mult power_add power_one_right cong_def)
  also have "[... = (1::int)^l * 3] (mod 4)" (is "cong _ ... _")
    by (intro cong_mult cong_pow) (auto simp add: cong_def)
  also have "[... = 3] (mod 4)" by auto
  finally have "[3^k ≠ 1::int] (mod 4)" by (auto simp add: cong_def)
  then show ?thesis using `odd k` by blast
qed
```

This is a pretty standard calculational proof, where we use `...` to refer to the RHS of the previous command. By default, it refers to the last argument of the top-level function application. In this case, that would be the modulus, so we override it with `(is "cong _ ... _")`.

Also note that we can avoid a large part of the work by reusing `minus_one_power_iff`:

```
lemma "[3^k = 1::int] (mod 4) ⟷ even k"
proof -
  have "[3^k = (-1::int)^k] (mod 4)"
    by (intro cong_pow) (auto simp: cong_def)
  thus ?thesis
    by (auto simp: cong_def minus_one_power_iff)
qed
```